# Creating Pie Chart with radius based on another field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, mapping, chart

I have to symbolize my ares polygon feature class and create pie Chart based on the following values in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop:

```
Area    Tds_Calc    Free_Chlorine   Ph    Fluoride  Turbidity   Failures
========================================================================

Area A  39.87           23.47       5.14     0          2.57     5

Area B  28.54           54.88       10.24   3.41        1.95    19

Area C  72.05            5.12        0.39   0.79        1.57    12

Area D  1.61             61.29       8.06   14.52       1.61    25

Area E  15               66.67       3.33      5        6.67    30

Area F  55.56            27.78       16.67     0         0       9
```

Pie Chart will be created based on the 5 fields and the last field, i.e. "Failures" should be used as radius of the pie chart. Thus, we will have size of the Pie based on the "Failures" and rest of the fields will be depicting the share of parameters.

How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are detailed instructions with dialog illustrations for this in the [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_pie_charts/00s500000016000000/).

In the layer properties on the symbology tab, choose pie under Charts. Add your fields to be depicted in the chart, then click the Size button at the lower right. That will bring up a dialog that has an option to vary the chart size based on a specific field, such as your Failures field. This related question has a picture of the dialog: [Sizing charts in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114916/sizing-charts-in-arcmap)

Note the value won't be used as a radius, but rather a factor - you'll set a minimum size in points to ensure your 5 value will still be legible, and it will scale up the symbol based on the larger values from there. This method is a combination of a chart symbol and the [proportional symbol](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_proportional_symbols/00s500000005000000/), which it may help to read about.

Comment: Thanks Chris. can we display the value of parameters also on Pie Chart. i was trying to display but unable to find any where.

Comment: @user34810 So far as I know, no, that isn't possible. Just as with the bar charts, the chart symbols can only show relative proportions and not specific values. You'd have to create an actual chart (as opposed to a chart symbol) for each polygon. As an aside, I note you have not accepted any answers to your questions. Please consider clicking the check mark next to an answer that solves your problem, both to reward those who have helped you out and to indicate the issue has been solved.