# Sizing charts in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, chart

In ArcMap I have to represent water data that has extreme disrepencies between the figures, so when I create a bar graph one graph is much larger than the others. Even if I convert these figures to a percentage it is 99% versus the others which are less than 1%. The only thing I can think of is to use pie charts of the same size, but then this doesn't show the visual aspect of the differences between figures by looking at it (e.g that one uses more water than the others).

Does anyone have better ideas on how to represent this data using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

also is there a way to move the placement of the charts so they don't cover my reservoirs?

example data:
reservoir a. 300,000 ML used 250,000 unused
reservoir b. 700ML used 10ML unused

update - I cannot remove the outlier because I have 9 regions, all with outliers that have higher amounts of water than the others. The only thing I can do is change the size of the pie chart based on a field but this causes some pie charts to be tiny dots, so I have had to create a ratio based on a scale to represent my figures.

I would have liked if it there was more I could do with charts, I can't label them and I would have liked to use the thickness slider bar in 3d pie charts as a field - so the height of the pie charts would change based on a figure. I create a label based on my layer but these get covered by the pie charts, the only thing I can do is set an offset.

Comment: I recommend that you research/ask your second question "placement of the charts so they don't cover my reservoirs?" because, as per the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) I think the focussed Q&A format we use here works best with "one question per question".

Comment: I'm also unclear on what you're trying to show. Chart symbols create charts based on fields in *each* record. An actual chart would be based on a single field but comparing *all* records. So water and dissolved whatever in each reservoir would work as symbols, but amount of water used from each reservoir would need to be a chart. If it's something like 99% of all water from each reservoir is used for irrigation and you're wanting to visually show the breakdown of other uses per reservoir, I would just exclude that outlier category from the symbology and note it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on what you are asking, and you editing your question to include a picture would help that, but there are two other options on the Pie Chart Size dialog, besides Fixed Size, that you could try:

[image]